# Frequent crashing of Youtube on Ubuntu16.04

Tags: youtube

I upgraded ubuntu to 16.04 a few days ago. After upgrading, the youtube website has been crashing quite frequently(It goes black and white and then hangs for few seconds,I don't know what it's called technically). Also,sometimes,my lappy's mouse stops functioning(only the bottom buttons work). Are these bugs in the OS itself or is something wrong with my PC?(This didn't happen earlier)

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue under Firefox. With Chromium everything works fine.

Comment: @Sammyak Sangai Using what browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that using Flash for Youtube add-on for Firefox solves the problem for the most part. you can find the download page here https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/youtube-flash-video-player/
Just make sure you get the flash logo on your addons bar, make sure its enabled and it should allow flash to be used in youtube without any trouble.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! You might be able to improve this answer with providing the steps needed in more detail and maybe even adding screen-shots of different parts to make it a rock solid answer.